# .NET Core 2 with MySQL on OSX

Tags: c#, asp.net, ef-core-2.0

I'm wanting to develop an ASP.NET Core Web API on VS for OSX (MacBook Pro) and want to connect to MySQL. I downloaded the MySQL.Data NuGet package but when I run the site it gives me errors/warnings that it's built for .NET framework and not built for .NET Core 2 and some other errors about System.Security.Permissions missing and the like.

VS on OSX only runs .NET Core 2 sites from the version I have it looks like, there are no options for .NET Core 1.1 or .NET Framework like VS Community. What I'm wanting to do is connect to my MySQL DB and run queries, I'll need Views/Stored Procs support, what I'm wanting to do will be mixed between ORM tables and running Views/SPs, and I'm not sure if that's available in EF Core.

What do I need to do to get up and running?

I'm already looking at Django/Python as it does what I need, but .NET Core is much sleeker for Web API I think. Would be great to run on VS/OSX as VirtualBox/Win 10/VS 2017 Community is very slow on my machine and not a good solution here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just had to get the Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql NuGet packages.

Comment: You should accept this answer to end the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to take a look at the DevExpress XPO that was ported to .NET Standard 2.0 a few weeks ago. Previously, this ORM existed for more than a decade, so it is stable and reliable already, because it shares 99% of codebase. To see what creating a Web API may look like, check out this demo: https://github.com/DevExpress/XpoNetCoreDemos/blob/master/XpoASPNETCoreDemo/DevExpress.Xpo.AspNetCoreDemo/Pages/Data.cshtml.cs

Examples for working with direct SQL and SP are given [here](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/8914/DevExpress-ORM-Tool/Feature-Center/Querying-a-Data-Store/Direct-SQL-Queries) and [there](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/9216/DevExpress-ORM-Tool/Examples/How-to-Access-Data-in-SQL-Query-Results) in the online documentation. Mapping persistent classes to database views is also supported. There is also a large [support knowledge base](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/List/1) with questions answered for the last 13 years or so (see under the Frameworks (XAF & XPO) on the right side). As for tooling, there is a visual designer (for Visual Studio for Windows) and Nuget support for the rest (I think [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/visualstudio/mac/nuget-walkthrough) will help you). See this [tutorial to get started](https://documentation.devexpress.com/CoreLibraries/119377/DevExpress-ORM-Tool/Getting-Started/Getting-Started-with-NET-Core).